# PowerVR - GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY on glDrawElements

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, powervr-sgx

I've encountered `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error after call `glDrawElements` on PowerVR GPUs. This happens on the following devices:

- Motorola Atrix 2 with stock 4.0 (PowerVR SGX540)
- Gigabyte GSmart GS202 with stock 4.x (PowerVR SGX531u)
- Some LG phone with stock 4.x (also with some PowerVR chip).

According to [`glDrawElements` specs](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml) it can't result in `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error at all but I definitely get this error on PowerVR hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by some bug in ETC1 texture implementation. If I use a ETC1 texture with dimensions of 1x1 pixels it causes this bug on *PowerVR* GPU. I've fixed it by using 4x4 texture (a size of ETC1 smallest block).

This issue is not reproduced if ETC1 textures are used with mipmaps - in this case it works w/ all mipmaps.